# Which form of QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I need to create a map of a state  showing water features - I'll need to remove alot of smaller water features from the file.   Which version of QGIS should I download? The latest release standalone installer for new users, 32 or 64 bit, or the OSGEO4W Network Installer, 32 or 64v bit? **Will you  version for new users  allow me to create that type of file?**

Comment: If you are a new user, use the installer for new users. Take 32 or 64 depending on your operating system.

Comment: Will the new user version allow me to create that file?

Comment: WHAT type of file?
... Anyway, there is no difference in file type support between the different QGIS installers for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You should install 32 or 64 bit depending on your computer requirements (if you have a 32 bit computer, do not install 64 bit version)

Other than that, I believe all downloadable qgis versions contain an option to select features from the map, and create a new layer with the large water featuers you want.